# Loop with setTimeout with different delays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to make a kind of playlist of events, where each event has a specific play time and the next one has to play after the time's up and so on.

Currently I'm using the `setTimeout` function. Now I would need to loop to get my events and times.

My code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < playlist.length ; i++){
     setTimeout(function(){
           $('#ventana').attr({src: playlist[i].url_play});
     }, playlist[i].time_play*i);                   
}
```

But the timing is not right. How can I correct this?

Comment: You shall review [ask] to learn more about making questions which will help readers understand your issue and increase the chance that you get a helpful answer to your issue.

Comment: sorry, I'm a new member... I have already done some corrections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will indeed not work if you set the delay to `playlist[i].time_play*i`: think of it... It does not take into account the delays for *past* playlists, only the current one -- multiplied by its index(??).

Instead you would need to accumulate the *different* delays, for instance in a `delay` variable:

```
for (let i = 0, delay = 0; i < playlist.length ; delay += playlist[i].time_play, i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#ventana').attr({src: playlist[i].url_play});
    }, delay);                   
}
```